# Tikzfading as watermark image

Tags: tikz-pgf, watermark

I have imported a graphic and stored it as a grayscale tikzfading with the command:

```
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=thefading, inner sep=100]%
  \node [fill={transparent!0}]%
    {\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{thegraphic}};%
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
```

I now want to use `thefading` as a watermark; that is I want to put it at the center and at the back of the page, with the original width and height, and with a level of opacity and colour of my chosing. I have tried the following command with trashy results:

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
  \node[%
    path fading=thefading,%
    fit fading=false,%
    fill=blue,%
    fill opacity=.2,%
    minimum width=8cm,%
    minimum height=8cm]%
    at (current page.center) {};%
```

I hope somebody can help me in this one. Thanks in advance.

PS: By the way, what does exactly `inner sep` mean? I don't understand the explanation in the manual. Here, I use the value 100 because it has an effect when I double fade the graphic: it removes the coloured line around the final tikzimage. But I discovered this just by playing around with the code. Several other values also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems that fading does not cooperated with a full `overlay` picture, perhaps because then it is not clear what the dimensions are. One simple possibility to work around this is to store the result in a `\savebox`, which you can use for your watermark. If you use this watermark on several pages, this method has the advantage of being a bit faster.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newsavebox\FadeBox
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=thefading]%
\node[transparent!0]{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=8cm]{example-image-duck}};%
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
\savebox\FadeBox{\tikz{%
\path[path fading=thefading,fit fading=false,fill=blue] 
(-4,-4) rectangle
(4,4);}}%

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
\node[opacity=0.2] at (current page.center){\usebox\FadeBox};}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, `inner sep` controls the distance between the node contents and its border. Setting it to `100` is interpreted as `100pt`, which is somewhat similar to `4cm`, which is why this may have helped you. Nonetheless I feel that the `\savebox` route is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks again, @Schrödinger'scat.