# How to put a watermark in a series of pages using only tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, watermark

With the help of [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507663/154737) I've defined a `tikz` based command for printing an image saved in a box as a watermark:

```
\newcommand{\tikzwater}[2][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
    \node[#1] at (current page.center)%
      {#2};}}
```

The optional argument `#1` allows me to pass key-value options to the node, like `opacity`. If I want to print the picture saved in `\mybox` with an opacity of .1, all I have to do is calling:

```
(1) \tikzwater[opacity=.1]{\usebox\mybox}
```

at the begining of each page.

Now comes the challenge of making a command that does this automatically.

More precisely, I want a command:

```
(2) \beginwater{\usebox\mybox}
```

that calls (1) at the begining of each page of the document, starting at the page where (2) is called. I also want a command:

```
(3) \endwater{\usebox\mybox}
```

that stops the calling of (1), again, at the page where (3) is called.

This command would be the last in a series of commands I made only using the packages `tikz` and `pgfkeys`. This is why I'm not satisfied by the answers given to previous similar questions, which are based on using other packages such a `background`, `eco-pic`, `watermark`, etc. The closest I know is [David Carlisle's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130999/154737) answer, but it doesn't let you decide where to begin and end the printing of the watermark.

I hope someone can give me a hand on this one.

Comment: You could do that with the `eco-pic` package, where `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` allows you to add a background picture to this and all subsequent pages, and `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` adds a picture to this page only.

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat, but I'd rather not use other packages except `pgf/tikz`. That is, unless you can convince me that there's a good reason for making an exception for `eco-pic`.

Comment: `eso-pic` allows you to put things really on the background (and so does `atbegshi`).

Comment: Well you need to add the code to a hook on every page (and remove it at the end). And you can do this either by using a hook provided by someone else (e.g. eso-pic or atbegshi or ...) or by writing the needed code yourself. I would do the first - much less work - but if you have free time you can go for the second.